# Predicate free variable property inference

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic

Excuse my naivety if I am completely wrong, I'm trying to learn.

Say I have a predicate asserting that x is greater than all x of its type with a certain property.

That is ( my best attempt at this... ):

a = { all elements of type of x }

b = { n | n $\in$ a $\land$ n "describes" x }

So of course.. 
$x \in a \land x \in b$

$p(x) = x > \forall y : y \in a \land y \in b$

or in english, specifically : "Input human x is heavier than all humans of x's race"

..Only **b** is my inference, in the english translation, there is no **b** subset of **a** given. Intuitively, the set of humans with a certain race is obviously a subset of all humans. Is there a valid inference that could be made in the english predicate that would lead to the conclusion that there is one free variable? It seems impossible to know the subset **b** unless the type was explicitly given (eg. human Bob, caucasian) since its not defined, to allow for choosing the correct subset of the set of "all humans". Or, is the set "all humans of x's race" just known as a result of race being some sort of intrinsic property of x?

The "weight" part is less confusing as this is just nested predicate that asserts whether two input humans are heavier/lighter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid for a moment of the "type" of $x$, i.e. of the "domain of discourse" $a$.

Then :

> "asserting that $x$ is greater than all $x$ of its type with a certain property (call it $P$)"

is :

> $\forall y (P(y) \to x > y)$.

As you can see, the formula has one free variables : $x$.

If we want to "restrict" the domain of discourese to a set $a$ (all humans, or all caucasian) we have to introduce a new suitable predicate symbol $A$ :

> > $\forall y [(A(x) \land A(y) \land P(y)) \to x > y]$.

---

*Note*

Presumibely, we have to add the clause : $x \ne y$ ...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had a feeling it was something like this, I just didn't know if it was valid to infer the existence of "A()" that tests for type